# Mismatching namespaces in Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, asp.net-core

I tried to use Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection nuget with my ASP.NET 6 vNext app and I found out there is mismatch between namespaces. The package is build with 1.0.0-beta8 and ServiceDescriptor inside 1.0.0-beta8 sits inside Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjectionm however my app uses later 1.0.0-rc1-final asp.net library and inside this library Microsoft moved ServiceDescriptor to different namespace - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

So If I'm not mistaken, I can't use it until Autofac will deploy new update of Autofac.Framework.DependencyInjection to the nuget, right?

Comment: This question would be better posted on the [issues](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues) page on github

Answer (score 0):

[Use Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2015/10/05/upcoming-rename-autofac-extensions-dependencyinjection/)